# How to change resolution or icon sizes on Xfce?

Tags: xfce, resolution

I have used Xfce nicely in my previous computer. My new gaming computer has a more accurate screen. I feel the icons are a bit too small for me. Is there either a way to customize the resolution or to customize the size of all graphical elements on Xfce?

Answer (score 4):

To change the icon size, go to Settings -> Desktop -> Icons.
To change the resolution, go to Settings -> Display.

Also, as far as I am aware, you cannot change the icon size in the default applications menu in the panel. If you want more control over the application menu, I would suggest installing whisker menu which allows you to change the size of the pop-up and/or the size of the icons.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the resolution by going to Menu > Settings > Display and changing the resolution